# $E_\infty\mathrm{Spaces}(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z},GL_1(E_n))$ and Eilenberg-Maclane spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, chromatic-homotopy

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbf{Z}}$Let $p$ be a prime. In his answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/135677), Jacob Lurie conjectured that $E_\infty\mathrm{Spaces}(\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z},GL_1(E_n))\simeq K(\Z/p\Z,n)$ where $E_n$ denotes the Morava E-theory associated to a formal group law of height $n$ over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$. In the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135641/strictly-commutative-elements-of-e-infty-spaces/135677#comment349574_135677), Charles Rezk provides a method of proof at heights $n=1,2$. Could someone explain Rezk's comment?

I think this conjecture has been proven now, by Hopkins-Lurie (this is in Lurie's third lecture at the 2015 Summer Institute on Algebraic Geometry; the notes are available at https://sites.google.com/site/2015summerinstitute/home/videos_notes). The result therefore holds for general $n$, but I'd still like to understand the approach outlined by Rezk.

Comment: It's a calculation, which is outlined in my uncompleted draft http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~rezk/power-ops-ht-2.pdf (I do plan to finish this some day).  The basic idea is to interpret the space (actually, I do $E_\infty$ maps from $Z$ to $GL_1(E)$) as a space of maps between $E_\infty$-rings (i.e., $\Sigma^\infty_+ Z$ to $E$), and set up a spectral sequence to compute it, whose $E_2$-term is described using homological algebra associated to power operations.  (BTW, I'd still like to understand the approach of Hopkins-Lurie; those notes you cite say nothing about the proof.)

Comment: @CharlesRezk Thanks! I'll read the draft. I think the notes http://www.math.harvard.edu/~amathew/notes_thursday.pdf contain a proof of the result (in the first lecture by Lurie).